# node.js youtube-audio-stream module net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING error

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, youtube, stream

When I'm streaming audio from the NPM module youtube-audio-stream, after a couple of minutes of playback, the audio just stops and in the Google Chrome developer console I see "Failed to load resource ... net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING".

Nothing in the network tab that might be helpful.

My code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var youtubeStream = require('youtube-audio-stream');

router.get('/stream/:videoId', function (req, res) {
    try {
        youtubeStream(req.params.videoId).pipe(res);
    } catch (exception) {
        res.status(500).send(exception)
    }
});
```

Link to the module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-audio-stream

This happens quite often, sometimes it plays successfully, sometimes the audio just cuts out.

EDIT:
I checked the server and found this error when the audio stream is interrupted:
https://gyazo.com/68a22d8c0660a40d16d8d62c39f1a733

Comment: You may have one or more proxies in the middle which terminate the stream. Those proxies can be configured to have more or less timeout intervals.